# How to prove terence tao proposition 9.3.9

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Proposition 9.3.9.  Let $X$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, let $f : X → R$  be a function, let $E$ be a subset of $X$, let $x_0$ be an adherent point of $E$, and let $L$ be a real number. Then the following two statements are logically equivalent:

(a) $f$ converges to $L$ at $x_0$ in $E$. (i.e $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0 s.t \forall x \in E $ and $|x_{0}-x|\leq \delta , |f(x)-L|\leq \varepsilon$)
(b) For every sequence $(a_{n})_{n=0}^{\infty}$ which consists entirely of elements of $E$ and converges to $x_0$, the sequence $(f(a_{n}))_{n=0}^{\infty}$ converges to $L$.

I am having difficulty proving (b) implies (a).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f(x) \not \to L $ when $x \to x_{0}$

Then there exists a $\varepsilon >0$ such that for every $\delta > 0$ there exists some $y \in E$ such that $|y- x_{0}| < \delta$ and $|f(y) - L| \geq \varepsilon$

If we take for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\delta_{n} = \frac{1}{n} $, then we have that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $y_{n} \in E$ such that $|y_{n} - x_{0}| < \delta_{n} = \frac{1}{n}$ and $|f(y_{n}) - L| \geq \varepsilon$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

But $|y_{n} - x_{0}| < \frac{1}{n} \implies |y_{n} - x_{0}| \to 0$ thus $y_{n} \to x_{0}$

But by hypotesis we have that $f(y_{n}) \to L$, then is a contradiction.

Comment: I also tried something similar